# Unity | Animated Rotten Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, normals

I Just wanted to ask what is the best practice to create an animated rotten tomato, that is from goot to turn to rotten animated. Or in general to create rotten vegetables animated, or even faces to turn out old etc etc..

I am new to unity so every hint/step would be highly appreciate!

Comment: The's no generally best approach, sometimes you might be better off doing the animations by hand, sometimes on the cpu, and finally on the GPU (shader), I would personally recommend the last approach

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a shader

the reason is that on the animator you can create a smooth transition from 1 material to another without all the rest of the states in the middle.